# "JQuery not defined" throwing error after installing angular-slickgrid

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-slickgrid

First let me clear one thing I have gone though https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-slickgrid/wiki/HOWTO---Step-by-Step and followed each step which is mandatory required. Anyhow let me show you what step i have followed

1. Installed angular slickGrid `npm i angular-slickgrid`
2. Added required css and js in angular.json

```
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
    "node_modules/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css",
    "node_modules/angular-slickgrid/lib/multiple-select/multiple-select.css",
    "styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js",
    "node_modules/slickgrid/lib/jquery.event.drag-2.3.0.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "node_modules/angular-slickgrid/lib/multiple-select/multiple-select.js"
],
```

3. imported AngularSlickgridModule in app.module.ts properly

   `imports: [ AngularSlickgridModule.forRoot() ]`
4. already i have installed required package for angular slickgrid

   package.json

```
  "@angular/animations": "^9.1.9",
  "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
  "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.9",
  "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.9",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.9",
  "@angular/router": "^9.1.9",
  "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
  "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
  "@types/jquery": "^3.3.38",
  "jquery": "^3.3.1",
  "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
  "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
```

[image: error msg]

Comment: Angular-Slickgrid dependency of jQuery is at latest version `"jquery": "^3.5.1"`, you could remove it completely from your `package.json` it will be installed anyway since it's a dependency of the lib. It's always much easier to clone the [Angular-Slickgrid-Demos](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-slickgrid-demos) to get you started and/or inspect the code, if you spot any problem with the Wiki then provide the Wiki changes by opening an issue. Lastly, there's 2 `scripts` in the Angular.json, make sure it's not just in the Test part since that won't help you get started

Comment: I'm seeing this exception very occasionally on load (< 1% of the time) - reloading my webpage in the browser fixes it. The stack trace looks slightly different, but the exact same error message "jQuery is not defined" in slick.cellrangedecorator.js:80 along with the "__webpack_require__" and bootstrap in the stack trace. I am using angular-slickgrid  2.30.5 and jquery 3.5.1 in my package.json. Probably some kind of race condition but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with `angular-slickgrid@3.x` on Angular 12, I found this workaround. In `app.component.ts` add:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
window["$"] = $;
window["jQuery"] = $;
```